# Обрабатывать вставленный текст на экране без полей ввода

Tags: android

Я использую специальный андроид прибор для лазерного сканирования баркодов. На нем есть специальная кнопка которая считывает баркод и вставляет результат в любое поле ввода в фокусе на экране. Мне нужно чтобы я смог принимать обрабатывать результаты в своем приложении, когда на экране нет никаких полей ввода. Нужно что то вроде аналога **addTextChangedListener** для **EditText**.

Comment: Так а каким образом происходит получение текста перед вставкой в поле ввода (код бы приложить)? Перехватить нельзя этот момент никак? Там же api прибора не напрямую с EditText работает?

Comment: В приборе уже есть своя api, и вне зависимости от того в каком состоянии телефон (только если не выключен) я могу специальной кнопкой просканировать баркод (прибор издает соответствующий звук когда просканировал). Есть сторонние sdk типа Zebra где есть всякие **barcodeListeners**, но я предварительно хотел узнать если ли стандартный способ получать и обработать результат сканирования без каких либо полей ввода.

Comment: Так как я узнаю, как вытащить текст из апи, которое в жизни не видел?) Если работает в фоне, то действительно нужно получать результаты по broadcast receiver, или есть возможность как-то подключиться к апи и следить постоянно за событиями? Если да, то можно сервис запустить, который будет подключаться к апи и слушать в фоне постоянно.

Comment: Просто как я понял тут действие стандартной вставки в поле ввода, и функция вставки срабатывает даже если нет никаких полей, и я подумал может можно как то получать результат этой вставки путем стандартных методов в Андроиде.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Какая стандартная вставка? Не может прибор взять и вставить в Ваше приложение какой-то текст, если приложение не прописало необходимые разрешения/бродкасты/сервисы или просто в коде к апи не подключалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный сканер баркодов работает по т.н. технологии *клавиатурного разрыва*, когда отсканированный баркод эмулирует ввод с клавиатуры, то есть по сути для внешней проги сканер баркода воспринимается, как клавиатура.

Но как только вы захотите получить баркод вне поля клавиатурного ввода сразу же возникает проблема - вам нужно иметь доступ к API сканера уже на уровне программного интерфейса. Сразу же вслед за этим начинается туча сложностей: модель сканера, драйвер, сигнатуры вызова API и проч. проч. Не думаю, что это то что вам надо.

Можно попробовать следующий хак:

1. Декларируете `EditText`, который невидимый, то есть с XML атрибутом `android:background="@null"` или программно: `edittext.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)`
2. Устанавливаете фокус ввода на него через `editText.requestFocus()`
3. Вешаете на него слушатель, который следит за его контентом
4. Сканируете баркод
5. Как только слушатель сообщит, что поле ввода непустое, копируете сканированный текст туда куда вам надо и немедленно очищаете поле.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно было. Так как я использую этот edittext в **alertdialog** то я написал так:
`edittext.setBackground(null);`
`edittext.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);`
`edittext.requestFocus();`
`edittext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`
Атрибут **INVISIBLE** я вставил, потому что после сканирования на пустом поле появлялся результат сканирования. И еще один вопрос, можно ли сделать так чтобы этот **edittext** не занимал место в диалоге?

Comment: Это вряд ли - попробуйте изменить размеры `EditText` до минимальных. Установите ему размер маленький шрифта - как вариант

Comment: Как добиться что бы очищались предыдущее, что было просканировано в EditText?

Comment: все нормально, выкрутился