# Получить значение сканера cipherlab rs30?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть сканер cipherlab rs30 на android.

Нужно обработать программно значение barcode, который просканировали, что бы потом искать по этому шк в базе данных товар.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Данные из камеры получаю, а мне нужно получить данные из встроенного сканера (на "голове" устройства)

Comment: Прошу помощи.

Мне нужно очищать предыдущий отсканированный баркод
как это с помощью extWatcher.afterTextChanged сделать?
как не кручу http://paste1c.ru/nwa или штрихкод добавляется до предыдущего или очищается вовсе штрихкод и ничего не добавляется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечал уже на схожий вопрос, но мне в лом повторить:

Стандартный сканер баркодов работает по т.н. технологии клавиатурного разрыва, когда отсканированный баркод эмулирует ввод с клавиатуры, то есть по сути для внешней проги сканер баркода воспринимается, как клавиатура.

Но как только вы захотите получить баркод вне поля клавиатурного ввода сразу же возникает проблема - вам нужно иметь доступ к API сканера уже на уровне программного интерфейса. Сразу же вслед за этим начинается туча сложностей: модель сканера, драйвер, сигнатуры вызова API и проч. проч. Не думаю, что это то что вам надо.

Надо просто встать с курсором в поле `EditText` и отсканировать баркод - в поле немедленно отобразится отсканированный баркод (его алфавитно-цифровой код). Дальше уже с ним можете делать все что хотите.

Если это не то что вы ищете - переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: К сожалению, EditText  не подходит ибо в EditText уже нужно вывести найденную или не найденную номенклатуру из базы

На счет "разрыва", да, в курсе и как раз мне нужно получить значения сканера вне какого то поля и я надеюсь, кто то подскажет пример как это сделать

Comment: Сделайта скрытый `EditText`, в который вводится баркод и уже оттуда после распознавания баркода найденной в БД значение выводите куда надо

Comment: типа на EditText поместить обработчик и после окончания ввода обрабатывать полученные в EditText данные?!

Comment: да, что то не выходит
http://paste1c.ru/j76
а если показываю поле то textView заполняется

Comment: сканер вряд ли будет генерировать ввод каретки

Comment: и как победить?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `TextWatcher.afterTextChanged`

Comment: А почему сразу очищается поле ввода http://paste1c.ru/a9e ?

Comment: потому что после ввода каждого символа вы очищаете через `clear()`

Comment: мда, а как правильно реализовать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659090/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0 ?

Comment: Я уже писал вам (см. выше в коментах) - больше мне нечего добавить

Comment: все ровно очищает http://paste1c.ru/xBg ранее чем добавляет

Comment: спасибо, разобрался